# how to do this query with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, where-clause

I have three models.

```
Mailing

  has_many :trackers, :as => :trackable
  has_many :links

Link

  belongs_to :mailing
  has_many :trackers, :as => :trackable

Tracker

belongs_to :trackable, :polymorphic => true
```

The trackers table has the following columns

trackable_id       trackable_type

Say I have a mailing object of id 1.

I want to get all of the trackable objects of type "Link" and "Mailing"

```
mailing = Mailing.find(1)
```

mailing.trackers gives me all of the objects that match trackable_type = "Mailing" trackable_id = 1

I want to get all of the records for this mailing from the trackers of both trackable types.

When I do

```
mailing.trackers.where(:tracker_id => mailing.links, :trackable_type => "Link")
```

I get nothing.

How can I get this data?

Thanks

Comment: Right now mailings are associated with trackers, and links are associated with trackers.  However, there is no association between mailings and links.  You may want to look into a `has_many :through` relationship between mailings and links.  Perhaps if you expound on the relationships you want between mailings and links we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this as follows:

Mailing.rb

```
Tracker.where("trackable_id = ? and trackable_type = ? or trackable_id in (?) and trackable_type = ?",self.id, "Mailing", self.links, "Link")
```

This returns all there records of both type Mailing and Link for the given ids.